# What TLS protocol does Server.CreateObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP.6.0") use?

Tags: iis, asp-classic, tls1.2

I'm using *classic asp* on *IIS* on *Windows server 2012*, and `Server.CreateObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP.6.0")` to make soap requests against a payment processor, and "suddenly" it stopped working.

The payment processor has disabled TLS 1.0, we're supposed to do TLS 1.1 or 1.2; I think this is the cause of the problem...

How do I see and if needed change which protocol it uses?

Comment: https://forums.iis.net/t/1220682.aspx?ServerXMLHTTP+6+0+WinHttpRequest+connecting+to+TLS+1+2+server

Answer (score 0):

Take a look here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/tls#systemdefaulttlsversions - specifically at sections SystemDefaultTlsVersions and SchUseStrongCrypto. You should also go ahead and disable all insecure ciphers/protocols/key exchanges in SChannel - the windows component responsible for SSL/TLS.

There is a GUI tool called IISCrypto from a company called Nartac that has some common profiles that are (somewhat) safer than editing the registry directly for disabling various obsolete components. see https://www.nartac.com/Products/IISCrypto.

***Word of warning** - be careful with your SChannel settings (either editing the registry or using IIS Crypto) - the settings are used throughout windows and are required for services like RDP and WinRM among other things - backup first, then test carefully.*

Answer (score 0):

I had similar situation - I have used Msxml2.XMLHTTP for API endpoint call in VB script and suddenly it stopped working. I got error "The system cannot locate the resource specified" and http.status returned 12029. The problem was not in the URL, it worked when I tried to call the URL from the browser. But when I started VB script, it has failed on the line http.send.

**How I solved it finally?**

I hade to install recommended update to my Windows Server 2012:

```
Microsoft .NET Framework 4.8 for Windows Server 2012 for x64 (KB4486081)
```

and I have installed one optional update too:

```
Internet Explorer 11 for Windows Server 2012 for x64
```

After this and server restart it started to work again. I can use both: "Msxml2.XMLHTTP.6.0" or "Msxml2.XMLHTTP", it does not matter.